# How to add library from custom remote repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I want to add a library from custom remote repository to my Java project but I couldn't manage to do it.

Library is published at a [custom Maven repository](https://github.com/esig/dss#maven-repository):

```
<repository>
  <id>cefdigital</id>
  <name>cefdigital</name>
  <url>https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/content/repositories/esignaturedss/</url>
</repository>
```

The library I'm trying to use is named [dss-rest-client](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/#browse/search=keyword%3Drest-client:esignaturedss-snapshots%3Aeu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss%3Adss-rest-client%3A4.8-SNAPSHOT) (Package name: [eu.europa.esig.dss.ws.signature.rest.client](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/apidocs/eu/europa/esig/dss/ws/signature/rest/client/package-summary.html))

I tried adding the repository XML to `<project>/pom.xml` and `<home>/.m2/settings.xml`. I also added the URL to `Settings -> Build Execution Deployment -> Remote Jar Repositories`.

But when I try to use search in `Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> Maven - Search` nothing comes up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refresh maven project in IDEA.

Comment: It is not always possible to search in repositories. It is better to add the Maven coordinates (GroupId, ArtifactId, ...) by hand into the POM.

Comment: Does maven actually download the dependencies when you add them in `dependencies` section? If you have added the repository - it should be present in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Repositories** tab. Do you see it there? If the repository contains the index file - the IDE will index it after you press **Update** button in Repositories settings for this repository.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't do what I wanted (add libraries from search interface) but I managed to add them as artifacts using pom.xml. You need to define repository in a profile and use that profile to maven build. You may need to restart IntelliJ after adding dependencies. Sample profile:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>myprofile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault><!--makes this profile the default profile-->
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>cefdigital</id>
                    <name>cefdigital</name>
                    <url>https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/content/repositories/esignaturedss/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```